# Complexity of multiplying matrix

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, matrices

Let's consider the following algorithm to multiply squares matrix:
`A` is a matrix of `NxN`. 
`r_i, r_j` defines interval of rows. For example `r_i = 2, r_j=3` means the second and the third rows. `c_i, c_j` means the same as `r_i, r_j` but for columns. We assume that `N = 2^s` for some `s`.

```
mul(A, B, r_i, r_j, c_i, c_j){
if(r_i != r_j){
   r_m = floor((r_i+r_j)/2)

   mul(A, B,  r_i, r_m, c_i, c_j) 
   mul(A, B, r_m+1, r_j, c_i, c_j)
} else if(c_i != c_j){   
   c_m = floor((c_i+c_j)/2)
   mul(A, B, r_i,r_j, c_i, c_m)
   mul(A, B, r_i, r_j, c_m+1, c_j)
}else{
 for i = 1 to N:
    C[r_i][c_i] += A[r_i][i] * B[i][c_i] 
 }

}
```

And the most important:

Complexity of that algorithm takes: T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n = O(n^2)

And it is not correct. The correct answer is O(n^3). Why my computation is incorrect.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)?

Comment: Note that O(n²) and O(n³) are not contradictory statements. Are you after $\Theta$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "please check my work" questions are unlikely ever to be useful to anyone except the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is not right... 
$$
U(R,C) = 2U(\frac{R}{2},C)\textrm{ or } 2U(R,\frac{C}{2})\\
U(1,1) = O(n)
$$

Basically, you have $N^2$ unique positions (which you drive your way down to recursively, rather than just looping) - for each of those you do a loop of O(N) so you have $O(N^3)$

Comment: This is not the way the code works currently. It's only $2U(R/2,C)$ or only $2U(R,C/2)$.

Comment: My algorithm is now correct? @Moti, can you edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm can be unrolled to the usual $O(N^3)$ matrix multiplication algorithm. If you open up all the recursive steps you will get a recursion tree whose $N^2$ leaves are of the form `mul(A, B, r, r, c, c)`, each of which has running time $\Theta(N)$, for a total of $\Theta(N^3)$.

Comment: I know this. I would like to see how to to compute complexity for **my** algorithm. Because it is hard to me.

Comment: I have just shown you how to compute the complexity for **your** algorithm.